# Prove that closure of A and A have the same accumulation points.

Tags: general-topology

(¯A=cl(A))

I have two attempts in mind.

(1) Show that the equality holds when A is closed, and when A is open.
(2) Show  A'⊆¯A' and ¯A'⊆ A'.

My attempt:

(1) We can show that ¯A'=A' when A is closed.

When A is closed, (recalling the theorem: A is closed iff A=¯A) the derived set of A is the same as the derived set of ¯A (i.e. A'=¯A').

This means, ¯A and A have the same accumulation points when A is closed.

Now we are left to show that ¯A'=A' when A is open.

When A is open, let p∈A, then we can find an open ball B(p,r)⊂A. Since p is arbitrary, we know that every point of A has a neighbourhood (open ball) that contains at least one point of A. Hence, p is an accumulation point(i.e. every point in A is an accumulation point).

(I don't know what to do from here. How to show the accumulation points of ¯A is the same as that of A?)

(2) We can also show by definition: the intersection of the set of accumulation points of A and the set of accumulation points of B is equal to the set of accumulation points of the intersection of A and B (i.e. A'∩B'=(A∩B)').

So,
A'∩¯A'=(A∩¯A)'

Since A⊆¯A, then
A∩¯A=A.

This gives
A'∩¯A'=A',

A'⊆¯A'.

Now we are left to show that ¯A'⊆A'.
(I have no idea how to show this)

Please advice.

Comment: To get $\bar {A'}$ or $\overline {A'}$ type \bar A' or \overline {A'}

Comment: Terminology: A neighborhood of $p$ is a set $N$ such that there exists an open set $O$ such that $p\in O\subset N.$ An open nbhd of $p$ is an open set that contains $p$.

Comment: A set may be neither open nor closed so if something is true for closed sets and for open sets it may fail to be true for other subsets.

Comment: I tried but it still has no effect. Can you help me out?

Comment: Does this mean I should stick to the second attempt? But I don't know how to prove the converse.

Comment: My advice: stick to the definitions.

Comment: You mean in the second part? What definition are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Definition:The closure of $A$ is defined as the common intersection of the family $F_A$  of all the closed sets that have $A $as a subset. Since the intersection of any family of closed sets is closed, therefore $\overline A$ is closed. And since $A$ is a subset of every member of $F_A,$ therefore $A\subset \cap F_A=\overline A.$

(i). Any member of the complement $\left(\overline A\right)^c$ of $\overline A$ belongs to an open set, namely, to $\left(\overline A\right)^c$, that is disjoint from $A.$ (ii). On the other hand if $p$ belongs to any open set $U$ that is disjoint from $A$ then  $U^c\in F_A$ so $U^c\supset \overline A$ so $p\not \in \overline A.$

Therefore by (i) and (ii) above, $p\not \in \overline A$ iff there exists an open set  that contains  $p$ and is disjoint from $A.$  Hence  $p'\in  \overline A$ iff every open set containing $p'$ has non-empty intersection with $A.$ (So we  could take that as an equivalent definition of  $\overline A.$)

$\bullet \;$.That is,  $p\in \overline A \iff p\in A'.$.. Therefore  $\overline A=A'.$

Now from the definition of the closure  of a set, if $B$ is closed then $B\in F_B$ so $\overline B=B.$ Applying  this, and $\bullet\;$, with $B=\overline A,$ we have   $$\left(\overline A\right)'=B'=\overline B=B=\overline A=A'.$$

Comment: The notation $F_A$ is just something I made up.

Comment: How did you jump to p is an element of closure of A also the derived set of A? Two sets both contain the same point does imply equivalence, right?

Comment: I meant doesn't necessarily imply equivalence...

Comment: I don't understand. Where exactly is it unclear?

Answer (score -1):

Its not able for me to type some symbols in my phone.Thats why I send this figure.please check this [image]

Comment: Please correct me ..if I'm wrong

Comment: You should rewrite you answer your mathjax to improve readability.

Comment: Actually..I'm using maths stack exchange in my phone.So that I can't able to write some symbols. I will check for other keyboards to write it.

Comment: Since I could not able to copy and paste, I sent it typed in another application.Please check..